# How to show / hide custom view depending the contentOffset of my tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a chat app and I'm trying to show a custom view that I've made when the user scrolls to the top, also hide it if it's on the bottom of tableview. (like whatsapp does it)

To be honest I'm struggling with the logic of show/hide button.
Tried to save the contentOffset.y of my tableview right after I reload the data so I'll know that's the bottom, and if it's smaller to show the custom view, but mainTableView.contentOffset.y it's always 0.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView == mainTableView) {
        print(mainTableView.contentOffset.y)
        if let point = startingPointForView {
            //where var startingPointForView: CGFloat?
            // and tried to save it after I reload the data
            //self.startingPointForView = self.mainTableView.contentOffset.y
            // but it's always 0
        }

        // Show and hide button logic

    }
}
```

An image of what I m trying to achieve:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRPpV.jpg

Comment: i think instead you can use scrollViewDidEndScroll ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code to hide/show custom view according to `UIscrollview` `contentOffset`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let scrollViewContentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
        let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.height

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < (scrollViewContentHeight - scrollViewHeight){
            //Custom view show
        }else{
            //Custom view Hide
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will help you

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y > 0 {
        // down
        button.isHidden = false
    } else {
        // up
        button.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is looking to hide a button when tableview is scrolling can use below code:

var previousContentOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat()

extension YourViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView == self.yourTableView{

        let currentContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        if (currentContentOffset > previousContentOffset) {
            // scrolling towards the bottom
            if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 50 {
                self.yourButton.isHidden = true
            } else {
                self.yourButton.isHidden = false
            }
        } else if (currentContentOffset < previousContentOffset) {
            // scrolling towards the top
            let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

            // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
            if maximumOffset - currentContentOffset <= 10.0 {
                self.yourButton.isHidden = true
            } else {
                self.yourButton.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        previousContentOffset = currentContentOffset
    }
}
```

}